# Issue with read Xbee Data

Tags: pi-3, communication, xbee

Here, I am interfacing Xbee(Rx) with raspberry pi 3 (Model B) and on another end Xbee(Tx) with Arduino UNO. On the Tx side I have a mechanical tool which is sending two types of data. But I am not able to understand this data properly.

I am using this code on receiving end.

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
        port ='/dev/ttyUSB0',
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1
)

while True:

    x = ser.readline()
    print (x)
```

I am receiving this data :-

> b'\x01\x1e(\x0b\x04\x02\x01\x1e(\x0b\x04\x02\x01\x1e(\x0b\x04\x02'
> b'\x01\x1e(\x0b\x04\x02\x01\x1e(\x0b\x04\x02\x01\x1e(\x0b\x03\x02'

But I can't read this data properly.

1.Can any one suggest to me how to make this data readable?
2.How can I save both data on different variables ?
Thank You

Comment: What are you sending - would be worth posting the Arduino set up code.  Data you have is mainly binary rather than character data (denoted by the b at the start) Python can handle binary data like this as byte stings strings e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-binary-data-in-python/

Comment: Sorry just to add without knowing what the chip is sending I **GUESS** x01\x1e( is start of data and \x0b\x04 or \x0b\x03 is the data and \x02 is the end of data but its a total guess